# Проблема с определением источника данных

Tags: css, http, post, get, request

Решил написать клиента для чата и не могу разобраться с начальным запросом.

Анализирую трафик и ни как не могу понять откуда прилетают `randid` и `id=shard2%` сессии
`randid` дается при входе на сайт, `id=shard2%` обновляется каждый раз при старте чата

вход на сайт

```
GET/status?nocache=111111111111&randid=222222222222_____________| textViev пусто
```

старт чата

```
POST/start?rcs=1&firstevents=1&spid=&randid=222222222222&lang=en__| 4E {"events": [["waiting"]], "clientID": "shard2:33333333333333"} 0
```

прием сообщения

```
POST/events id=shard2%на-33333333333333_______________________________| 16[["gotMessage", "текст"]]0
```

посыл сообщения

```
POST/send________________________________________________________| msg=hi&id=shard2%33333333333333
```

отключение

```
POST/disconnect___________________________________________________| id=shard2%33333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в браузере отключены кукисы. Если они отключены, то идентификаторы сессии автоматически добавляются к урлу